# Node app setInterval() on RaspberryPI stops randomly... Again

Tags: node.js, server, raspberry-pi

after some researching, I found multiple threads about this problem, but none of these helped me yet.

I have an app which periodically sends http-requests to a list of pages in order to get data from them. It works fine for about 3-4 hours, but it suddenly stops running. I tried adding "nohup", but it also didnt help.

The code I have with setInterval:

```
setInterval(iterateItems,(1000*60*5),urlsList);
```

running using: `nohup node index.js > ~/logs/scraper.txt &`

I have no clue about why this doesnt work for me.

The code itself which is called in iterateItems() has no errors, there are also no errors returned when the app suddenly stops running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have a raspberry pi, for node I did like this `setInterval(function() { ... YOUR FUNCTION HERE  .... }, 30 * 60 * 1000);` give it a try and see if it works for you I have no idea why this is happening have tried something similiar with a new js file that just says hello world from time to time? That way you can see if the problem is because of the function or the setInterval

Comment: thanks @AndréClérigo, i will try the hello world thing.

Comment: I think it is `setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`